# jquery validation for number >= 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to do validation like the following scenario.

If the value of drop down is "yes", then check if the text box value is >= 100 and return true
else return false

```
Rules:{
valid:{
    required: function() {
    return $('#req').val() == 1; //this checks if the drop down value is yes
    //here after this value becomes true, i want to check if the value in "valid" field    is >=100 and based on that i want to return true. 
      }
    }
},
Messages:{
 required : "Enter years",
 IsNumeric: "Enter numbers only"
}
```

The text box (id = valid) is dependent on the dropdown(req) field. If req is yes, check whether the valid field has numbers only and chek if the value in valid field is >=100. if not numbers only validate it (this has been done already). If the numbers are >=100 display a message. Can someone help out to validate if the entered number is >=100

Comment: why you using return if you want to do something after that line of code ?
return $('#req').val() == 1;

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
valid:{
    required: function() {
      var $dropdown=$('#req');
      var $textBox=$("#valid");
      var number = parseInt($textBox.val(),10);
      number = isNaN(number) ? 0 : number;
      if($dropdown.val() == 1){
        return number >= 100;
      } 
      // other values for $dropdown that might need to be checked:
      return true;
}
```

This will return true if the dropdown is 1 and number higher than 100 and true if dropdown isn't 1. The comment "other values for ..." is where you can add other checks for dropdown in combination with maybe other elements.